# array_flip() error when using phpunit

Tags: testing, 9

I've got a form, which when I use normally works perfectly fine, but when I load the form in phpunit I get the following error :

> 1. Drupal\digest\tests\DigestSubscriptionFormTest::testFormDisplay
>    Exception: Warning: array_flip(): Can only flip STRING and INTEGER values!
>    Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageBase->loadMultiple()() (Line: 261)

Within `buildForm` I have something like this :

```
    $digest_storage = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('digest');
    $digests = $digest_storage->loadMultiple();
    $subscription_storage = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('subscription');

    /** @var \Drupal\digest\Entity\DigestInterface $digest */
    foreach ($digests as $digest) {

      $query = $subscription_storage->getQuery();
      // There should never be more than one ID returned.
      $subscription_id = $query->condition('digest', $digest->id())
        ->condition('uid', $this->currentUser->id())
        ->execute();

      /** @var \Drupal\digest\Entity\SubscriptionInterface $subscription_entity */
      $subscription_entity = $subscription_storage->load(current($subscription_id));
      $entity_exists = isset($subscription_entity);
```

Now when I am using this on my own it works just fine. No errors or warnings at all.

As soon as I get the page from phpunit I get the above error. Here's the test

```
  public function testFormDisplay() {

    $this->drupalLogin($this->adminUser);

    // Create some basic digests to view.
    $digest_storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('digest');
    $digest_storage->create([
      'id' => 'viewOne',
      'label' => 'View One',
      'enabled' => TRUE,
      'title' => 'Custom Title',
      'description' => 'Custom description',
      'send_at' => 'Monday',
    ])->save();
    $digest_storage->create([
      'id' => 'viewTwo',
      'label' => 'View Two',
      'enabled' => FALSE,
      'title' => 'Ghost',
      'description' => 'I\'m invisible',
      'send_at' => 'Friday',
    ])->save();

    // Load the subscription form.
    $this->drupalGet(Url::fromRoute('digest.digest_subscriptions'));
```

Adding the `drupalGet` line makes the test fail. If I remove the creation of the entities it works.

I'm not only wondering how to fix this but also why? This is a functional test so it should have a full site meaning I should be able to use the entityTypeManager as normal correct? Mocking is only needed for unit and some kernel tests right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code shown for `buildForm()` there are two calls to `loadMultiple()`:

- The explicit call in the `$digests = $digest_storage->loadMultiple();` line
- The implicit call in the `$subscription_entity = $subscription_storage->load(current($subscription_id));` line

The second line is an implicit call to `loadMultiple()` because the default implementation of `load()` ([`EntityStorageBase::load()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityStorageBase.php/function/EntityStorageBase%3A%3Aload/9.0.x)) uses the following code.

```
assert(!is_null($id), sprintf('Cannot load the "%s" entity with NULL ID.', $this->entityTypeId));
$entities = $this->loadMultiple([$id]);
return isset($entities[$id]) ? $entities[$id] : NULL;
```

[`EntityStorageBase::loadMultiple()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityStorageBase.php/function/EntityStorageBase%3A%3AloadMultiple/9.0.x) uses the following code.

```
$entities = [];
$preloaded_entities = [];

// Create a new variable which is either a prepared version of the $ids
// array for later comparison with the entity cache, or FALSE if no $ids
// were passed. The $ids array is reduced as items are loaded from cache,
// and we need to know if it is empty for this reason to avoid querying the
// database when all requested entities are loaded from cache.
$flipped_ids = $ids ? array_flip($ids) : FALSE; // This is line 261, in Drupal 9.0.x.
```

`array_flip()` raises the *Can only flip STRING and INTEGER values!* warning when the array passed as argument doesn't contain a string or an integer value, which also happens when the array contains one or more `NULL` values, or even `FALSE` values.
This means, for example, that the following line isn't setting `$subscription_id` to an integer or a string, possibly because there aren't any *digest* entity whose ID is `$digest->id()` associated with the *subscription* entity, or associated with the currently logged-in user.

```
$subscription_id = $query->condition('digest', $digest->id())
  ->condition('uid', $this->currentUser->id())
  ->execute();
```

This is the probable cause, giving that the code of that test isn't creating any *subscription* entity. If creating a *digest* entity is supposed to create a *subscription* entity, then it's not creating a *subscription* entity that is associated with a *digest* entity with that ID or with the currently logged-in user.

(I assume `$digest->id()` is returning an integer, since that is the usual case. I would verify that too, but since it's the test that is failing, it seems more probable the cause of the warning is the one I described.)

Comment: A beautiful answer. Turns out there was an error generating normally it was just not showing up on the site at all. Since there were not sub entities the value of `current($subscription_id)` was false and that caused the crash. Thank you so much.